# How do I use a variable for the name of a table in a DBI query?

Tags: perl, dbi

How do I using a variable for the name of a table in a DBI query? I know how to use placeholders as part of the where clause, but how do I do this for the table name?

I would like to do something like this:

```
 my $table_name='table1';
 my $query = $dbh_cgi->prepare("select * from ?");
 $query->execute($table_name);
```

So far, I end up getting a MySQL syntax error because DBI adds quotes around the name, table1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the limitations of placeholders is that they can't be used for table names.  Instead of using a placeholder, you can use a variable.  To make sure the variable's contents are safe, use `quote_identifier()`, for example:

```
my $table_name='table1'; #-- Or get this from somewhere else
my $safe_table_name =  $dbh_cgi->quote_identifier($table_name);
my $query = $dbh_cgi->prepare("select * from $safe_table_name");
$query->execute();
```